# "Allowed to use third-party cookies" is not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

Google Chrome version : 121.0.6167.86

While opening one of the site, getting 'Cookies Disabled' error.  So I have added site name in '
Allowed to use third-party cookies' under Privacy and security  and selected 'Allow third-party cookies' option.  I restarted the browser, but still I am getting the same issue - 'Cookies Disabled' error in Chrome.

Thanks in advance.
RK